# The church of St Mary, St Mary church or St Mary's church?

Tags: grammar

I've found different ways of referring to the **name of a church** and I ask if we should use the possessive case for the title of a chuch: for exemple should we say St Paul's church or St Paul church?

Comment: The church of St Mary or St Mary's church.  But check with the church (look on-line), as established entities may have a pre-determined style

Comment: Most churces use the first or the third. The second is so uncommon that people often refer to _Augustine United Church_ in Edinburgh as "St Augustine's", though there is no "St" in its name.

Comment: In my area, we have a couple things officially named "St Person Adjectives Thing", but in speech consistently called "St Person's".

Comment: The formal name might be 'The Parish Church of St. Mary, Anytown', but parishioners probably refer to it as 'St. Mary's'.